# Python 3.4.2 logging not displaying time stamp

Tags: python, logging

I have a Python pgm that I'm trying to add logging to.  It is logging, but is not adding the timestamp to each entry.  I've researched it, read the docs, etc, and it looks correctly written to me, but it isn't giving me the timestamp.  What is incorrect here?

```
lfname = "TestAPIlog.log"
logging.basicConfig(filename=lfname, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                filemode='w', level=logging.WARNING )
logging.info('Started')
```

The top of the log produced by the above looks like this:

```
INFO:root:Started
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.uber.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /v1/estimates/price?end_latitude=39.762239&start_latitude=39.753385&server_token=MY_TOKEN_HERE&start_longitude=-104.998454&end_longitude=-105.013322 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.uber.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /v1/estimates/price?
```

Thanks,

Chop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if something has already called `basicConfig()` by the time your code runs. As documented, `basicConfig()` does nothing if logging has any handlers configured. It's only intended as a one-off, simple configuration approach. Check the other parts of your code which you didn't post here.